# work with function serialize and insert data array to database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

how can insert data array`<input name='hello[]'>` with function [serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) in database?

please give me a example simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply like...

Controller :

```
function foo()
{
    if( ! empty($_POST))
    {
       $hello = serialize($_POST['hello']);
       // You can do your database abstraction here, but is better to have these in your model
       // Btw, by using CI AR, all values are escaped automatically producing safer queries.
       $this->db->insert('some_table', array('hello' => $hello)); 
    }
    else
    {
       // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
$sSerialized = serialize($sData);
INSERT INTO table SET field = ".myqsl_real_escape_string($sSerialized);
```

I wouldn't advice storing serialized data into your database though.

For a codeigniter specific setup, I think you can see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html